# Sonata Blocks page__block table

Tags: symfony, sonata

I am working on a project that was created with Symfony2 Framework and Sonata Components.
I am not the creator of this project.

I do not understand something: I have a table called page__block. I do not understand how this table is feed. Is it a cache of sonata ?
How should i purge and re-feed this table ?

There is some sonata commands from app/console for cache and blocks but those commands do not affect my page__block table.

Comment: Wich version of symfony 2 and sonata are you using ? Are you talking about sonata admin bundle ?

Comment: I am not talking about sonata admin bundle.
I am talking about full sonata project, which contains sonata admin bundle. How can i know symfony and sonata versions on an existing project ?

Answer (score 0):

To find out wich version of symfony components you are using:

`$ composer show symfony/*`

For sonata bundles :

`$ composer show sonata-project/*`

It would be interesting to have the result of those two to help you further.

If i were you i would start by trying to find wich entity populates this table by looking in Resource/config/Doctrine in the non vendor bundles of your project